# Check if element exist and if not then update database c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, insert

As you can see below, I am trying to check first if username of new user already exists. If not, then to insert in database. My error is

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Must declare the scalar variable "@username".

I am thinking about taking off the second

```
cmdSignUp.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("username", username));
```

where my //comments are.

But it's not fixed.

I think it's all because I demand the input inside a using above the *Insert* using.

```
Console.WriteLine("Select Username");
string username = Console.ReadLine();

using (SqlCommand cmdSignUp = new SqlCommand("Select Count(*) from Users where Username = @username", conn))
{
    cmdSignUp.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("username", username));
    int UserExists = (int)cmdSignUp.ExecuteScalar();

    if (UserExists > 0)
    {                                
        Console.WriteLine("Username already exists. Please sign up again");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a password 6-8 characters");
        string password = Console.ReadLine();

        using (SqlCommand cmdPass = new SqlCommand("Insert Users(Username, Password) Values(@username, @password)", conn))
        {
            // maybe the error is here? If I delete it I am getting 
            // System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
            // 'Must declare the scalar variable "@username"
            cmdSignUp.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("username", username));                 
            cmdSignUp.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("password", password));

            int rows = cmdPass.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Console.WriteLine($"{rows} new user has been created. Press a key to go back to Main Menu and LogIn");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: These kinds of limitations should always be applied to teh DB Side. A unique constraint is one of the most trivial ones, every DBMS that supports Priamry keys needs ot have one. Moving these knds of checks into the Client only makes it more prone to error without giving you anything.

Comment: In Users Table in my db, the primary key is the Username. Could it be that I am just trying to re-Add as a parameter the username? Maybe there is a way to take it from the first time.

Comment: A string makes a poor primary key. It should be a integer, autovalue. You can still apply unique to other rows freely. If you want to know the value of something you just inserted, MS SQL has the "OUTPUT" clause. It allows access to stuff like the auto generated primary key of the row you just inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it an issue with your syntax I would replace the following lines with @username and @password

```
cmdSignUp.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", username));
cmdPass.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", username))
cmdPass.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", password));
```

Also, you're using the wrong reference in the else block you should be using cmPass instead of cmdSignUp

Comment: Same error.
the @sign in front of the Values(@username, @password)
makes the "assignment" from the users input.

Comment: Are you missing an "into" a la "INSERT INTO table"?

Comment: You have the syntax issues in three different places, edited my comment to include the additional place.

Comment: Thank you for you interest. Again, same error. I don't believe there's a syntax error. But I have one question, about your edit, why add 2 times the username parameter?

Comment: Think I nailed it this time. So, you're using separate SqlCommand objects. You have to assign the variables to each individual object. In the else block you're using cmPass not cmSignUp

There are multiple entries because there are 2 separate objects, hope this answered your question.

Comment: NAILED IT IT IS!!! and I just created a user named hopethatworks
password gogogo 
(hahaha)

Comment: Happy to help! Please accept the answer when you get the chance